# Surjectivity check when return type is sealed

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types, non-exhaustive-patterns

Scala can warn when pattern match on a sealed type is not exhaustive, however can we check that a function returns all cases when the return type is sealed?  For example, consider the following ADT

```
sealed trait Foo
case object Bar extends Foo
case object Qux extends Foo
```

Then function `f: Foo => String` on the algebraic data type `Foo`

```
def f(x: Foo): String = x match {
  case Bar => "bar"
}
```

raises warning

```
match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Qux
def f(x: Foo) = x match {
```

Is it possible to raise a similar non-exhaustion warning when return type is an ADT such as in the following implementation of `f: String => Foo`:

```
def f(x: String): Foo = x match {
  case "bar" => Bar
  // warn because we never return Qux 
}
```

Comment: I do not know if such warning may exists, but I doubt it exists, since there is nothing wrong about not having a case for every possible implementation. Probably the only place where this would be useful would be for a factory from name to instance _(which looks like what you showed)_. - Not exactly an answer, but you may be interested that [**Enumeratum**](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) will create such method for you, and since it is a macro it will contain all cases. Maybe, you may just write a similar macro to ensure there is at least one case for each implementation?

Comment: Also, you may try proposing this feature on the [**Scala contributors**](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/) channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is not really an answer, but it's too long for a comment anyway.

Pattern matching and function return values are two different things. Former operates on the *type* level, latter on the *value* level. When you pattern match on `Bar`, you're pattern matching on the type (just like e.g. `Int`). But when you return `Bar`, you're returning the case object value (just like e.g. `42`).

Surjective function is defined as:

> For every member *y* of the codomain, there exists at least one member
>   *x* of the domain, such that *f(x) = y*.

Now it's easy to see why this check is not feasible / possible. What if your `Bar` wasn't a case object, but a class? E.g.

```
final case class Bar(name: String, surname: String, age: Int)
```

You would need to expect every possible value of `Bar` to be used (e.g. name = "John", surname = "Smith", age = 42).

Of course, this is not what you intended; what you described is a scenario where each subtype has exactly one inhabitant, because `Bar` and `Qux` are basically enums, and I can see why such a check might make sense to you. But it would have to be implemented for the general case of arbitrary number of inhabitants per (sub)type - it would need to verify that codomain contains at least one value of type `Bar`, at least one value of type `Qux` etc. which doesn't sound very useful.

As I said, this is not really an answer, but I wanted to give you an insight into what exactly it is that you're asking. :) Perhaps someone wrote something with reflection and/or macros which could provide such a check, but not to my knowledge. Hopefully with Scala 3 enums you will never need to write such a function anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here are enumeration examples suggested by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez and @slouc which do provide case exhaustion:

**[enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)**

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait Foo extends EnumEntry
object Foo extends Enum[Foo] {
  val values = findValues
  case object Bar extends Foo
  case object Qux extends Foo  
}

Foo.withName("Qux")
```

**[Scala 3 Enumerations](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/enums.html)**

```
enum Foo {
  case Bar
  case Qux
}

Foo.enumValueNamed("Qux"))
```

Both methods worked fine even with parameterised sealed type.